# Does std::erase() and std::erase_if() cause reallocation of the vector?

Tags: c++, std

As the title of the question states, do any of `std::erase()` and `std::erase_if()` cause reallocation of the vector?

Which one is more efficient among the two: should I use the erase-remove idiom or should I use directly `std::erase_if()`?

I assume that no reallocation is supposed to happen since no additional memory is requested when removing elements from the vector but I would like to have a definitive answer to that.

Comment: The short answer is no. The elements are either moved or copied in-place.

Comment: They're both defined to use (just) `std::remove`/`remove_if` on iterators and `erase` from the container, so they have whatever guarentees the container gives on these operations.  In particular, the `erase` method of vectors is guarenteed to not reallocate.

Comment: Ref: [`std::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: *Removing* elements from a vector never causes a reallocation of the `vector`. Only *inserting* does that, and only when `size==capacity` before the insertion.

Comment: From cppreference on std::erase: "std::erase_if() replaces the erase-remove idiom.(since C++20)" So... what would you use instead? And: "**Complexity**
Linear: the number of calls to the destructor of T is the same as the number of elements erased, the assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements." That leaves no room for reallocation.

Comment: `std::vector` almost never shrinks its capacity. `shrink_to_fit()` does it, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two functions are [specified as being equivalent to erase-remove](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.erasure):

> Effects: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> auto it = remove(c.begin(), c.end(), value);
> auto r = distance(it, c.end());
> c.erase(it, c.end());
> return r;
> ```

> Effects: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> auto it = remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred);
> auto r = distance(it, c.end());
> c.erase(it, c.end());
> return r;
> ```

Looking at the [specification of `std::vector::erase`](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers), we see:

> Effects: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of
> the erase.
>
> Throws: Nothing unless an exception is thrown by the assignment
> operator or move assignment operator of T.
>
> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to
> the number of the elements erased, but the assignment operator of T is
> called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the
> vector after the erased elements.

In particular, this function does not change the capacity or invalidate any iterators before the first erased element.

---

As to performance, it's likely to be very similar, as the two approaches may [compile to near-identical object code](https://godbolt.org/z/KMq9eYP4j).  I recommend you optimise for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Reallocation only occurs when a vector grows. It is logically impossible for either `erase` or `erase_if` to make the vector bigger than what it was originally. No reallocation will ever happen.

As far as which one is more "efficient" that's mostly meaningless. The two methods are not comparable replacements for each other. If one needs to select values to remove based on some logical criteria, anything other than a fixed value, `erase_if` is your only option. No matter how hard you'll try you won't accomplish your goals with `erase`, but only `erase_if`, no matter how much the former is or is not "efficient".

And in a case when only a fixed value needs to be removed, it's fairly likely that most modern C++ compilers end up producing comparable, if not identical, code for both `erase` and `erase_if`. But, with modern multi-Ghz CPUs it's going to be extremely difficult to tell the difference; however `erase` results in much shorter, simpler code with fewer punctuation that C++ is notorious is for. Which is a good thing.

Comment: I think the efficiency question was about comparing `std::erase_if` to the equivalent `std::remove_if`+`vector.erase()` idiom, and `std::erase` to `std::remove`+`vector.erase()`, not asking for a comparison of `std::erase` and `std::erase_if`'s performance.

Answer (score 0):

> do any of `std::erase()` and `std::erase_if()` cause reallocation of the vector?

No as the capacity of the vector doesn't change. The elements past the end iterator are however destroyed.

> Which one is more efficient among the two: should I use the erase-remove idiom or should I use directly `std::erase_if()`?

Both should have same performance but there is a chance that erase-remove idiom is more performant than the `std::erase_if`. This can happen because `erase_if` takes a Predicate function which may not get inlined by certain compilers or at certain compiler optimization levels. If you are only interested in removing elements that are **equal** to a fixed value then erase-remove (or `std::erase`) idiom would be a better choice.

Note: There are different functions: `vector::erase`, `vector::remove`, `std::erase`, `std::erase_if`, `std::remove_if`.

- `std::erase` has the semantics of erase-remove idiom which is equivalent to calling `vector::remove` followed by `vector::erase`.
- `std::erase_if` has the semantics of calling `std::remove_if` followed by a call to `vector::erase`.

Comment: ah yes. corrected.

Comment: It's perhaps strong to say that `std::erase` and `std::erase_if` actually _call_ the mentioned functions.  They can be implemented directly, as long as the effects are the same.

Comment: I'm presuming that the version of erase-remove that's being compared to `std::erase_if()` would be using `std::remove_if()`, and should have the same performance (likely the same object code).  Otherwise it's not a like-for-like comparison.

Comment: "Re: actually call the mentioned functions."
true. i should clarify this as implementation specific.